# Typescript constructor which takes object instead of parameters

Tags: typescript

My constructor is starting to get long and not quite the way I like it. I'd prefer to pass an object to my constructor so I can reference fields by name. Here is the class now.

```
export class Group {
  id: string;

  constructor(
    public title: string,
    public isPublic: boolean,
    public comments: string = '',
    public targets: Target[] = [],
    public owner?: string,
    id?: string
  ) {
    this.id = typeof id === 'undefined' ? uuid() : id;
  }

  associatedTargets(targets: Target[]) {
    return targets.filter(target => target.owner === this.id);
  }
}

export default Group;
```

Right now, making a group is along ugly function. I'd prefer to pass

`new Group({title: 'test', isPublic: false, owner: 'me'})`

instead of `new Group('test', false, '', [], 'me')`.

Is there a better way to write this constructor that doesn't result in a bunch of:

```
this.title = title;
this.isPublic = isPublic;
this.comments = comments;
...
```

It appears I can do this:

```
export class Group {
  title: string;
  isPublic: boolean;
  comment: string;
  targets: Target[];
  owner?: string;
  id?: string;

  constructor({
    title,
    isPublic = false,
    comment = '',
    targets = [],
    owner,
    id,
  }: {
    title: string;
    isPublic: boolean;
    comment: string;
    targets: Target[];
    owner?: string;
    id?: string;
  }) {
    this.title = title;
    this.isPublic = isPublic;
    this.comment = comment;
    this.targets = targets;
    this.owner = owner;
    this.id = typeof id === 'undefined' ? uuid() : id;
  }
```

But I have to assign each property individually, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

You can define an interface as a Data Transfer Object so to say and pass that in as the constructor.

```
interface IGroupDto {
  title: string;
  isPublic: boolean;
  comment: string;
  targets: Target[];
  owner?: string;
  id?: string;
}

export class Group {
  group: IGroupDto;
  constructor(group: IGroupDto) {
    // ...from here handle initialization of what you need from the data object
    // or maybe the `Group` class just has a property that contains the constructor object
    // below the `id` assignment is handled, de-structuring the data object 
    // last will override the id set from uuid(). or you can do it similar to how you did
    this.group = {id: uuid(), ...group}
  }
}
```